# GROUP_CONCAT() like function to return fields that don't match?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have three tables in my database, for the purposes of discussion let's say they are:

```
USERS   
-----
user_id
user_name

ROLES
-----
role_id
role

USER_ROLES
----------
user_role_id
user_id
role_id
```

I can easily use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to return a comma separated list of roles the user **does** have like so:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(role) AS roles_held
FROM users u,
     roles r,
     user_roles ur
WHERE u.user_id = ur.user_id
  AND r.role_id = ur.role_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.user_name;
```

What I'd like to do is also return a list of roles the user does not have.

My initial thought was using sub-query then concatenating that, but I can't seem to get that to work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** To clarify, the desired output would be a query that returns the user_id, user_name, a concatenated string of the roles the user does have and a concatenated string of the roles the user does not have. So for example:

```
USER_ID    USER_NAME    ROLES_HELD      ROLES_LACKED
1          Bob          User,Writer     Editor,Admin
2          Doug         User            Writer,Editor,Admin
```

Comment: What exact output do you want here?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll edit the above post to make it more clear. I'm looking to get a query that would return each user, a concatenated string containing a list of the roles they do have as well as a concatenated string containing a list of roles they don't have.

Comment: Thanks for posting desired output but it's not much clear until you post the sample data.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with using a `CROSS JOIN` here, but it doesn't need to be quite so complicated:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(case when ur.user_id is not null then r.role end) AS roles_held,
    GROUP_CONCAT(case when ur.user_id is null then r.role end) as roles_lacked
FROM
    users u
    CROSS JOIN roles r
    LEFT JOIN user_roles ur ON
        u.user_id = ur.user_id
        AND r.role_id = ur.role_id
GROUP BY
    u.user_id, u.user_name
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is basically what I ended up using. I meant to accept this earlier but I was having trouble logging into my account here. I needed tech support for my tech support. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to join table role two times The first time to get held roles, the second time to get lacked roles.

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
       user_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.role)  AS role_held, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r1.role) AS role_lacked 
FROM   users u 
       INNER JOIN user_roles ur 
               ON u.user_id = ur.user_id 
       INNER JOIN roles r 
               ON r.role_id = ur.role_id 
       INNER JOIN roles r1 
               ON NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM   user_roles ur1 
                              WHERE  user_id = u.user_id 
                                     AND role_id = r1.role_id) 
GROUP  BY u.user_id, 
          user_name
```

I've created a demo [here](http://rextester.com/TSQ43559)

Comment: This is also excellent. Thank you so much. I'm going to be brushing up on my SQL a lot, but this helped me a ton in the meantime.